# integrate a variable '$u$' with a '$dx$', is that possible? (Basic Integrals)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

1. Are these integration written correctly?
2. is it possible to do integration like second one with the respect to $x$?

First: $$ \int (1+\tan^2(ax))\,dx =  \frac 1a \tan(ax) +c. $$
Second (This is not $u$-Substitution): $$ \int u’(1+\tan^2u) \,dx = \tan u +c. $$

Comment: $u'$ is supposed to mean $du/dx$. So the factor $u'dx$ is a chain rule factor, effectively equivalent to $du$. The whole integral is correct although you may need to remember the Pythagorean relationship between $\tan$ and $\sec$.

Comment: In my experience, if a student writes an integral containing both $u$ (or $du$) and $x$ (or $dx$), the student ALWAYS makes a mistake.  There may be no rule against it but I think it's a really bad idea.

Comment: @StefanSmith : What if the student writes this: $$ \begin{align} & \int \arctan x\,dx = \int u\, dx = xu-\int x\,du \\  \\ = {} & x\arctan x - \int x \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = x\arctan x + \frac 1 2 \log(1+x^2) +C \end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "written correctly", but the solution for the first integral is correct. The second integral is also correct, but despite your claim, this is in fact $u$-substitution. When calculating integrals in practice, you may use the fact that $u'dx=du$, and so the integral can be rewritten entirely in terms of $u$; this is precisely what is meant by $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $u'\,dx$ is the same thing as $\dfrac{du}{dx}\,dx,$ so it's the same as $du.$

$$
\int u'(1+\tan^2u) \,dx = \int(1+\tan^2u)\,du 
$$

However, if $u = ax,$ then $\dfrac {du}{dx} = a,$ so $dx = \dfrac{du} a, $ and you have
\begin{align}
& \int (1+\tan^2(ax)) \, dx = \int\frac{u'} a(1+ \tan^2 u) \, dx \\[15pt]
= {} & \frac 1 a \int(1+\tan^2u)\, du = \frac 1 a \tan u + C = \frac 1 a \tan(ax) + C.
\end{align}